# How to dynamically create a mock object from an interface?

Tags: .net, reflection, mocking, .net-core, middleware

Say I have the interface and class defined below.

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    void Method1();
    int Method2(int i);
    string Method3(string s);
}

public class MyImplementation : MyInterface
{
    public void Method1()
    {

    }

    int Method2(int i)
    {
        return i;
    }

    string Method3(string s)
    {
        return s;
    }
}
```

The `MyInterface` is defined in one class library and the `MyImplementation` is defined in a second class library.

Now say I have an application that depends on `MyInterface` and gets its implementation via dependency injection.  The application can simply reference the implementation class library and register `MyImplementation` with the IoC container, right? No big deal.

But say I have dozens of services and web applications that all depend on `MyInterface`, they're all using `MyImplementation` via DI, and I want to change that implementation of `MyInterface`.  I'd have to update and redeploy each application, which is doable but kind of a pain.

What I'm trying to accomplish is encapsulate the dependency in a service and develop some middleware that would automatically mock a specified interface on the client, convert calls to that interface to a web request (presumably via reflection), send that web request to the service, the service would convert the web request back to a method call on the same interface (again, presumably via reflection) and call the real implementation DI'ed into the services.  This would allow me to isolate the dependency to a single service that I can change at will without having to redeploy all the other apps and services.

First, this seems like a problem that some one should have already solved, but I can't seem to find any canned solutions.

Second, if I were to implement something like this myself.  How would I even begin?  Seems like I'm trying to do something similar to Moq or Rhino Mocks except I don't want to have to explicitly define what to do for each method.  I'd like to handle it automatically via reflection.  My service should receive a POST request with the body containing the FQN of the interface, the name of the method, and an array of parameters so I can find the method server side and invoke it.

```
public static class IServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddMiddlewareClient<T>(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
        var members = type.GetMembers(bindingFlags);

        var mockObject = ???

        foreach(var member in members)
        {
            // Mock each method on the interface with one that sends 
            // a web request to the service.
        }

        services.AddSingleton<T>(mockObject);

        return services;
    }
}
```

The service looks something like this.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IServiceProvider _services;

    public HomeController(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        _services = services;
    }

    [HttpPost("invoke/{typeName}/{memberName}")]
    public object Invoke(string typeName, string memberName, [FromBody]Parameter[] parameters = null)
    {
        var interfaceType = Type.GetType(typeName);

        var args = parameters
        .Select(p =>
        {
            var parameterType = Type.GetType(p.TypeName);
            var parameter = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(p.Json, parameterType);
            return parameter;
        })
        .ToArray();

        var impl = _services.GetRequiredService(interfaceType);
        var implType = impl.GetType();
        var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase;
        var result = implType.InvokeMember(memberName, bindingFlags, null, impl, args);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you thought on passing that mocked object as a dependency as well? is that an option?

Comment: Yeah, that's the plan.  What I'm trying to avoid is manually writing a class that implements the interface and makes web requests.  If there's a way I could automatically generate that object at run-time, that would save a lot of copy pasta.